# Traversing a single linked list in order

Tags: c++, linked-list, traversal, singly-linked-list

I have been trying to think a way to traverse a single linked list.

This is so far what I have done:

```
#include <iostream>

typedef struct node {                                                               
      int data;               // will store information
      node *next;             // the reference to the next node
};  


int printList(node *traverse) {
    if (traverse->next == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    traverse=traverse->next;
    printList(traverse);
    cout << traverse->data << endl;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    node *head = NULL;      
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        node *newEntry = new node;
        newEntry->data = i;
        newEntry->next = head;
        head = newEntry;
    }
    printList(head);
    return 0;
}
```

I cannot think a way to print the last digit(9) in `printList()` function. How would I be able to achieve this?
My second question is, how can I traverse the same in a while loop rather than a recursive function.

As some of you tried to answer before, I am not looking to traverse this from 9 to 0, This should traverse from 0 to 9, you can see the output from http://codepad.org/ynEdGc9S

Comment: If this is production code then use std::list. If not then enjoy.

Comment: @Bathsheba: More like `std::forward_list`.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few things here:

---

In `main()` the **way you are creating the list** is incorrect. Draw what you're doing, you'll realize that your `head` is the last item in the list, i.e., it will probably have a value of 9. (Print out head's value just before you call printList to verify this).

Let me explain (follow along in your code) with iteration of i = 1:

Current state: `head=[0]`

1. A new temporary node is allocated  `[ ]`
2. Then you assign data to it `[1]`
3. Then you set this temporary node's next to your head `[1]-->[0]  ; head=[0]`
4. Then you set head to this temporary node `[1]-->[0] ; head = [1]`

So, you can see what's happening here. Head should still be `[0]` and its next should be `[1]` not the other way around.

You can explore and think about the correct way of doing this.

---

printList, this is printing out the recursive stack and not the traversal. Traversal would print them in reverse order because your list is in the reverse order (check the previous section ^ for why).

This is the correct way to print the link in a traversal. This will print the elements of the list in the way they are.
*When you checked for traverse->next==NULL, traverse held the last element. Since you just ended the recursion by returned -1, the last element was never printed.*

```
int printList(node *traverse) {
   if (traverse == NULL) {  
       return -1;
    }
    cout << traverse->data << endl;
    printList(traverse->next);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Iterative

```
int printList(node *traverse) {
   while(traverse != NULL) {  
    cout << traverse->data << endl;
    traverse = traverse->next;
   }
}
```

---

Feel free to post questions, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `if (traverse->next == NULL)` try `if (traverse == NULL)`

This way, you print the current node if it's an actual node with data in it.  You then recurse.  Ultimately, at the end you will recurse into a `NULL` pointer, which you can easily escape.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you interchange these statements?

```
traverse=traverse->next;
printList(traverse);
cout << traverse->data << endl;
```

This should be changed to:

```
cout << traverse->data << endl;
traverse=traverse->next;
printList(traverse);
```

This should work. And then, change

```
if(traverse->next==NULL)
```

to

```
if(traverse==NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to the second part, your code could look like this:

```
void printList_iter(node* node)
{
    while (node)
    {
        cout << node->data << endl;
        node = node->next;
    }
}
```

This will loop through the list, printing each element until it gets to a NULL node, which signifies the end of the list. It's a pretty standard iteration algorithm.

Comment: This does not print what I want,
Mine prints from 0 to 8, whereas this prints from 9 to 0

Comment: @SarpKaya oh, sorry, I didn't realize the values were in reverse order. I'll fix up my code.

Comment: @SarpKaya actually, printing the list in reverse is far easier with recursion than with iteration. Why do you need this algorithm to be iterative?

Comment: Recently I have been asked in an interview. So I was wondering the answer.

Comment: @SarpKaya: This is because your version prints the list in reverse, this prints it in order like you asked.  The head is normally considered as the start of the linked list.  If you change this, then don't be surprised to get answers like this.

Comment: @SarpKaya if you want to do it iteratively (in reverse), you will need to use a stack data structure (to reify the implicit call-stack that would be produced if the algorithm were recursive). Do you want me to include that?