# How to display a linked list that gets struct data as a data in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this struct and I initialize it in my linked list class, but I am not sure how to display it:

```cpp
struct CourseData {
    string CourseID, MaxCapacity, CurrentCapacity ;
    string CourseName, InstructorName, CourseSection, CourseLocation, ListOfStudents;
};

class CourseNode {
    private:
        CourseData elem;
        //
        CourseNode* next;

    public:
        CourseNode(CourseData elem) : elem(elem)
        {}  
        friend class Courses ;

};

class Courses {
    private:
        
        CourseNode *head;
    public:     
        Courses();
        ~Courses();
```

What should I change to this code? It outputs an error:

```cpp
void Courses::display() const
{
    CourseNode *ptr=head;
    cout<<"Head->";
    while(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<ptr->elem<<"->";
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
    cout<<"Null"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: What exactly don't you know about how to display it? Please be more specific. You start with the `head` node, display its `elem` data, then move on to its `next` node, display its `elem` data, repeating for each subsequent node, until you reach the end of the list.

Comment: There's an example how to print linked list https://stackoverflow.com/a/17458675/3365922

Comment: ^To be precise, there's plethora of examples to find at SO and all over the internet.

Comment: i edited my post can you check my display function

Comment: Suppose you want to display one `CourseData`. How do you want to do it? What do you want to appear on the screen?

Comment: I want all my variables from CourseData appear

Comment: @Fantom the point Beta is making is HOW do you expect to do that? You don't have any function implemented that prints out a single `CourseData`, so you can't print out a list of `CourseData`s. Think about HOW you would print a single `CourseData`, and then you can expand on that for a whole list.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Courses::display()` method is fine as-is.  The real problem is that
`ptr->elem` is a `CourseData`, which `display()` is trying to pass as-is to `std::cout` via `operator<<`, but you do not have an `operator<<` implemented for `CourseData`, which the compiler complains about, eg:

```
prog.cpp: In member function ‘void Courses::display() const’:
prog.cpp:39:13: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream’ {aka ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’} and ‘CourseData’)
         cout<<ptr->elem<<"->";
         ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
```

So, you need to add that operator, eg:

```cpp
struct CourseData {
    string CourseID, MaxCapacity, CurrentCapacity ;
    string CourseName, InstructorName, CourseSection, CourseLocation, ListOfStudents;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const CourseData &data) {
    // print data's fields to the os stream as needed...
    return os;
}
```

Comment: thanks,but what do you mean by  write data fields to os as needed...

Comment: print `data.CourseID`, `data.CourseName`, etc to `os` using `operator<<`, just like you do any other value, eg: `os << "(" << data.CourseID << ":" << data.CourseName << ... << ")";`

Comment: i checked, it displays whole linked list with heap, but i want to display only data stored inside structure. How should i actually pass add atructure to linked list

Comment: Then you are not using the list correctly, or you are not printing it out correctly, but we can't see what you are doing. Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem in action.